# How can I stop the http server, downloaded using 'npm install http-server"?

Tags: http, npm, server, console

How can I stop the http server, downloaded using 'npm install http-server" comand in terminal (console) and launched then?

Comment: This seems to address the problem: [How to terminate a HTTP server in Node.js?](https://dev.to/gajus/how-to-terminate-a-http-server-in-node-js-ofk)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Its built on node so Kill the node process for stopping it if it stuck. You can find all the node process ids and see what I'd your server have and kill that.

Comment: How can I do it? I tried "killall node" - no effect - "No matching processes belonging to you were found"

Comment: what OS you are running?

Comment: Now I have a solution - lsof -i -n -P | grep TCP - it stopped the server (I'm trying to understand, how). But I would be grateful for explanation on how can I find all the node process ids.

Comment: sudo killall -9 node - "No matching processes were found"

Comment: you already killed it so that's why. now i'm not Mac guy work most on linux so not sure how mac work but in ubuntu i can simply list all the node process like this ps -aux | grep node

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](http://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/120869/discussion-between-mrjsingh-and-maxim-velichkin).

Answer (score 3):

Simply Ctrl+C, if you read the output after you launch it, you should see:

```
Starting up http-server, serving xxx
Available on:
  http://<some ip>:<some port>
Hit CTRL-C to stop the server
```

Comment: Thank you, but it doesn't work for me.  I think it happened after I launched the server with the command "npm start", which I wrote in the package.json file (server was launched after that) and then I changed the script of the command and put it into the console again, without stopping the server. Now Ctrl+C doesn't work (it works the same as Enter - moves to a new line in console)

Comment: Thank you, (though sad that I had to look this up here when the answer was staring right at me!)